# JSON_TABLE Filter Condition Issue

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm trying map a JSON array of objects to relational table columns using JSON_TABLE.
The Parts array consists of arrays of instruction arrays.  Each instruction array contains objects with consistent names of three name value pairs. The values of the name field are always "Family", "Feature", or "Price". These are not always in a consistent order within the array.   I thought I could use a filter condition within the columns clauses to map the correct value to the the correct column.

```
WITH STR AS (
select 
'
{
  "Parts": [
    {
      "instruction": [
        {
          "name": "Family",
          "value": "AJE",
          "type": "0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Feature",
          "value": "AJKA",
          "type": "0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Price",
          "value": "0",
          "type": "0"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "instruction": [
        {
          "name": "Feature",
          "value": "AJKB",
          "type": "0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Family",
          "value": "AJA",
          "type": "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
' JSTR
FROM DUAL)
SELECT JT.*
FROM STR SO,
JSON_TABLE(SO.JSTR, '$.Parts[*].instruction[*]'
           COLUMNS ("Family"  PATH '$."value"?(@.name == "Family" )',
                    "Feature" PATH '$."value"?(@.name == "Feature")',
                    "Price"   PATH '$."value"?(@.name == "Price")'
                    )
           )         
           AS "JT"
```

As the code is displayed, it returns five rows with all of the fields null. 
I realize the code above is wrong.  Below is another attempt.  This code will return the data (filter condition commented out and array indexes hard coded), but the column data is mapped wrong.

```
JSON_TABLE(SO.JSTR, '$.Parts[*]' --ERROR ON ERROR
 COLUMNS ("Family"  PATH '$.instruction[0]."value"', --?(@.name == "Family" )
          "Feature" PATH '$.instruction[1]."value"', --?(@.name == "Feature")
          "Price"   PATH '$.instruction[2]."value"' --?(@.name == "Price")
                    )



Family   Feature   Price
------   -------   -----
AJE       AJKA      0
AJKA      AJE   



I'm trying to return this:
Family   Feature   Price
------   -------   -----
AJE      AJKA        0
AJA      AJKB
```

Answer (score 1):

I wish StackOverflow folks would **always** indicate their Oracle Database version up front.

Anyway, this hack appears to work in version 18c:

```
SELECT ord,
  max(json_value(jt.Family, '$.value')) family,
  max(json_value(jt.Feature, '$.value')) feature,
  max(json_value(jt.Price, '$.value')) price
FROM STR SO,
JSON_TABLE(
SO.JSTR, '$.Parts[*].instruction'
COLUMNS (
  ord for ordinality,
  nested path '$[*]' columns (
    Family format json path '$?(@.name == "Family")',
    Feature format json path '$?(@.name == "Feature")',
    Price format json path '$?(@.name == "Price")'
    )
  )
)         
AS "JT"
group by ord
order by ord;
```

A better solution would be to simplify the JSON and use the PIVOT clause to manipulate the result:

```
select family, feature, price
from (
  SELECT jt.ord, jt.name, jt.value
  from str,
  JSON_TABLE(
    str.JSTR, '$.Parts[*].instruction'
    COLUMNS (
      ord for ordinality,
      nested path '$[*]' columns (
        name varchar2(100) path '$.name',
        value varchar2(100) path '$.value'
      )
    )
  )
  AS "JT"
)
pivot(max(value) for name in ('Family' as Family, 'Feature' as Feature, 'Price' as Price))
order by ord;
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**: ORD should count the instructions, not the individual values.

To put the values you want in the right columns, adjust your path:

```
SELECT JT.*
FROM STR SO,
JSON_TABLE(
SO.JSTR, '$.Parts[*].instruction'
COLUMNS (
  ord for ordinality,
  nested path '$[*]' columns (
    Family path '$?(@.name == "Family").value',
    Feature path '$?(@.name == "Feature").value',
    Price path '$?(@.name == "Price").value'
    )
  )
)         
AS "JT";

ORD FAMILY FEATURE PRICE   
  1 AJE                           
  1        AJKA                
  1                    0        
  2        AJKB                
  2 AJA
```

Now just group by ORD:

```
SELECT ord,
  max(family) family,
  max(feature) feature,
  max(price) price
FROM STR SO,
JSON_TABLE(
SO.JSTR, '$.Parts[*].instruction'
COLUMNS (
  ord for ordinality,
  nested path '$[*]' columns (
    Family path '$?(@.name == "Family").value',
    Feature path '$?(@.name == "Feature").value',
    Price path '$?(@.name == "Price").value'
    )
  )
)         
AS "JT"
group by ord
order by ord;

ORD FAMILY   FEATURE   PRICE   
  1 AJE      AJKA          0        
  2 AJA      AJKB
```

Best regards, Stew Ashton

Comment: Thank you.  This was very helpful.  I did get a syntax error on 18c, but I tried it on livesql, which currently says it is on 19c, and it worked correctly. I still need to try modifying it for 18c.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be determine `Ordinality` values for `NESTED PATH '$."Parts"[*]."instruction"[*]'` within the subquery to be used in Ordering of `ROW_NUMBER()` function grouped by `name` column's values, and `Pivoting` by `Family` and `Feature` columns :

```
SELECT "Family", "Feature" FROM
(
 SELECT value, name , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY rn) AS rn
   FROM STR,
        JSON_TABLE(jstr, '$'
                        COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$."Parts"[*]."instruction"[*]'
                        COLUMNS (rn FOR ORDINALITY,
                                 value VARCHAR2 PATH '$."value"', 
                                 name VARCHAR2 PATH '$."name"') 
                   )) )
 PIVOT
 (
  MAX(value) FOR name IN ('Family' AS "Family", 'Feature' AS "Feature")
 )                   
ORDER BY rn
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7a2724f7ba981d6d741c1bd78969007e)</kbd>